# Compilation error - inline code

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline-code

I'm using a 3-tier architecture for my application. I'm using inline code to call certain methods found in the business logic. I have a method which returns a particular string message. The following code is returning an error

```
<div id="logo">
<h1><a href="/" title='<%= systemMessagesBL.ReturnMessage("MSG_MAINPAGE_TOOLTIP", 1) %>'>Application</a></h1>
</div>
```

The error being: `CS0103: The name 'systemMessagesBL' does not exist in the current context`. And this although I already made a reference to it using the following embedded code:

`<% BusinessLogic.SystemMessagesBL systemMessagesBL = new BusinessLogic.SystemMessagesBL(); %>`

What may be the problem?

Comment: Can you put those 2 fragments into context? You can snip the irrelevant stuff in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your object in a code-behind file, not inline, and make it `protected`:

```
protected BusinessLogic.SystemMessagesBL systemMessagesBL = 
   new BusinessLogic.SystemMessagesBL();
```

then your inline stuff should pick it up.